# Static import in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, module

If I have a module with a public member and I use it like this

```
Module.Sub.member()
```

Then what is the best (if it exists) way to static import the member into local scope, like `using` in cpp or `import static` in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var App = (function(app) {

    /* Dependencies */
    var Sound = app.Modules.Sound,        
        Input = app.Modules.IO.Input,
        ...

    /* Actual code using dependecies */
    ...    


})(App || {});
```

This solution has several advantages:

- Stated at the top of a module, it's clearly visible at first glimpse (*maintainable code*) ,
- Usual benefits of imports: less typing, avoidance of namespace clashes etc. (*maintainable code*)
- Long property path look-ups (`a.b.c.d`) will be needed only once (*performance*) ,
- Using a local variable is faster, that using a global variable - quicker look-ups (*performance*),
- Minification tools *can* minify local variable names safely, but can't trivially minify global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
member = Module.Sub.member;
```

perhaps? However be careful, as it clutters the global object properties and may even end up overwriting some of those, since you have no notion of a "compilation unit", to which static imports are scoped in Java. Instead, you have a *single, dynamic* execution state of your VM, so the suggestion above is not a declarative but an imperative way to achieve what your are after.

To my knowledge, there is no way to declaratively achieve the same goal as `import static` does.

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach I find beautiful enough to point at :

```
(function(member) {
    //Your code here will see member in this scope.
}) (Module.Sub.member);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's the difference between `(function(){...}())` and `(function(){...})()` ?

Comment: @JoshuaMN `(function(){...}())` is not valid javascript. `(function(){...})()` is equivalent to : `var f=function(){...}; f();`